# Deploy Nuxt application in SPA mode on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy my Nuxt 2.10 application powered with @nuxt/typescript on Heroku.

I've create a Node application container with heroku/nodejs Buildpack and configure a free dyno as follow:

```
web
yarn start
```

At the same time I've initialized a fresh Nuxt project with some dependencies, I reported here the package.json to be as clear as possible.

The scripts part:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt-ts",
    "dev-debug": "npx --node-arg=--inspect nuxt-ts",
    "build": "nuxt-ts build",
    "start": "nuxt-ts start",
    "generate": "nuxt-ts generate",
    ... some lint and test scripts...
    "heroku-postbuild": "nuxt build"
  },
```

followed by depenencies:

```
 "@nuxt/typescript": "^2.8.1",
    "@nuxt/typescript-runtime": "^0.2.2",
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.8.4",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.7.1",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^1.3.3",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-0",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.10.2",
    "nuxt-property-decorator": "^2.5.0",
    ...lots of stuffs here
```

and finally the devDependencies:

```
"@nuxt/typescript-build": "^0.3.4",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^1.1.2",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^0.1.3",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "browser-env": "^3.2.6",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^0.4.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "husky": "^3.0.9",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "require-extension-hooks": "^0.3.3",
    "require-extension-hooks-babel": "^1.0.0",
    "require-extension-hooks-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    ... and others
```

Luckily Heroku is awesome and I report the crucial part of Heroku build log:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (31:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
> @Component({
|   components: {
|
 @ ./pages/xxxx/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& 1:0-120 1:136-139 1:141-258 1:141-258
 @ ./pages/xxxx/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
 FATAL  Nuxt build error
  at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:5314:21)
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
  at async WebpackBundler.build (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:5263:5)
  at async Builder.build (node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js:5597:5)
  at async Object.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-build.js:100:7)
  at async NuxtCommand.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-command.js:2575:7)
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
   ╭─────────────────────────────╮
   │                             │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error        │
   │                             │
   │   Error: Nuxt build error   │
   │                             │
   ╰─────────────────────────────╯
```

Obviously, develop ad build application in local environment with **yarn dev** works like a charm

I would say that the problem is clearly with Heroku, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Any kind of help is really appreciated

---

**Update**

Just update the heroku-postbuild script in package.json and nuxt build successfully.

```
"heroku-postbuild": "nuxt-ts build"
```

But now, I've just encountered a new problem which I report the build log:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       YARN_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.11.1
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  1.19.1

       Resolving node version 12.11.1...
       Downloading and installing node 12.11.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.11.3
       Resolving yarn version 1.19.1...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.19.1)...
       Installed yarn 1.19.1

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.19.1
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       success Already up-to-date.
       Done in 1.35s.

-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild (yarn)
       yarn run v1.19.1
       $ nuxt-ts start
 WARN  No .env file found in /tmp/build_87.........xc/.
 FATAL  No build files found in /tmp/build_87.........xc/.nuxt/dist/server.
Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode.
  Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode.
  at VueRenderer._ready (node_modules/@nuxt/vue-renderer/dist/vue-renderer.js:4226:13)
  at Server.ready (node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:607:5)
  at Nuxt._init (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:655:7)
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
   ╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                                     │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                                                │
   │                                                                                     │
   │   Error: No build files found in                                                    │
   │   /tmp/build_87.........xc/.nuxt/dist/server.                    │
   │   Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode.   │
   │                                                                                     │
   ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
error Command failed with exit code 1.
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Ok, I'm crazy. Just change "heroku-postbuild" to "nuxt-ts build".

Comment: Hi, It'd be nice if you could post your solution as an answer rather that updating the question